# jQuery .done function not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In the following JS the .done function is firing in FF, Chrome, and Opera however in IE 10 and lower it doesn't go off. The idea of it is grabbing a unique identifier from the url will allow the code to decide which photoset is grabbed from a Flickr account and displayed in the slider to be used in an iFrame later. However when it comes to IE10 and lower the .done seems to get completely skipped over. Anything below .getJSON call is ignored.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var photoSetId = ['72157638321110124','72157638320688146','72157638320892573','72157638320142195', '72157638319052975'];
    var setNum = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
    var user = '110468775@N05';
    var apiKey = 'fa3bd9c48f711aef070622ba60014b21';
    var photoset = photoSetId[setNum];
    var flickr = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/';
    $.getJSON( flickr, {
        method: "flickr.photosets.getPhotos",
        nojsoncallback: 1,
        extras: "original_format",
        api_key: apiKey,
        photoset_id: photoset,
        privacy_filter: '1',
        format: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each( data.photoset.photo, function(i, item ) {
            var url = 'http://farm' + item.farm + '.staticflickr.com/' + item.server + '/' + item.id + '_' + item.originalsecret + '_o.jpg';
            var $li = $("<li>");
            var $img = $("<img>").attr('src', url);
            $img.appendTo($li);
            $li.appendTo('.bjqs');
        });

        $('#slider').bjqs({
            'height': 360,
            'width': 640,
            'showcontrols': true,
            'centercontrols': true,
            'showmarkers': false
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Check your error console and network tab.

Comment: I would assume that the request is not returning JSON that IE deems valid, so it is failing silently.

Comment: does `nojsoncallback` result in a cors rquest rather than JSONP? oldIE doesn't support CORS in jquery without the addition of ajax transports to handle IE cors.

Comment: Why are you using `nojsoncallback` anyway?

Comment: @Kevin Well, if I don't use the nojsoncallback the entire thing stops working on any browser. I'm not exactly sure what it does no, I found it while going through the flickr api pages and it fixed a prior issue.

Comment: *"Well, if I don't use the nojsoncallback the entire thing stops working on any browser"* That's good, at least it's consistently failing in all browsers. Now all you have to do is tell jquery to use jsoncallback as the callback param rather than callback. `var flickr = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?';`

Comment: @Kevin Dude you rock, absolutely correct that fixed it. If you want to post that as an answer so I can flag it I will do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working in all browsers other than IE because all browsers other than IE support CORS with the XmlHTTPRequest object, while IE requires the use of the XDomainRequest object instead prior to IE11.

To fix this, swap to using jsonp by removing the nojsoncallback parameter, then add the jsoncallback parameter to the flickr url so that jquery knows where to put the callback name for the flickr api.

```
var flickr = 'http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?';
$.getJSON( flickr, {
    method: "flickr.photosets.getPhotos",
    //nojsoncallback: 1,
    extras: "original_format",
    api_key: apiKey,
    photoset_id: photoset,
    privacy_filter: '1',
    format: 'json'
})
```